# Just publish modified controllers, models and some parts of a ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, publish

If I change my views (`.cshtml`) or styles (`.css`) or scripts (`.js`) in my MVC projects then I can publish it easily by right click on it and select `Publish FILE_NAME`

[image: publish file example]

If I changed some controllers files or BLL classes or infrastructure classes,

- Which files should be published? which DLLs?
- Of course added references must be published but what are another?
- Should I publish all the DLL files in the bin folder or just some?
- Is there an easy way to VS detect modified files and publish theme by a command or...?

---

**Edit1**

I use FTP method to direct publish and upload our site to the server.

My Publish Preview Step Snapshot:
[image]

- What is the name of DLL files that contains the compiled information of controllers, BLL classes and...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just published the `MVC5Bootstrap-3-1-1-Less.dll` and it worked!

So if we uploaded a website and then want only publish the new modified controllers or classes of the MVC web application (here: MVC5) to the server, we should upload the following files:

- MVC5Bootstrap-3-1-1-Less.dll after build
- Added references to the bin folder after build

Here is a image of how publish DLLs of bin folder from Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: Ah, I am truly grateful. Worked for my simple app where I needed to change a font style in the controller create watermark code. Had one main dll and followed you instructions. I love it because then I can make changes on the fly and not deal with overwriting a well configured web.config file on the server or image folders (yes, I know I can configure release and debug versions of web.config.. .. but sometimes. . . . )

Answer (score 5):

The publish wizard on the project (right click on project > Publish...) should automatically determine which files have changed and need to be updated, and show you what files will be updated.

[image]

After clicking Start Preview:

[image]

Comment: i added a new picture of my project to the question, there is not Start Preview button on my window. Also i wrote a question below it, that is important for me. what do you think about this?

Comment: It looks like you're using FTP publishing, I'm not sure if FTP publishing is capable of comparing existing files or not. You could either look into web publishing, or just publish everything every time. That's way to ensure you get all your changes. In general though- any time you are changing C# code (except for razor files!) you will need to publish any DLLs that reference that C# code. This is because the C# code is compiled into that DLL, so any changes will not be published if the DLL is not published.

Comment: i checked the files inside bin folder and test a way and it worked, so i inserted a new answer.